# como convierto un str de input en un int o float? en python

Tags: python, float

tengo este codigo, pero no se como convertir ese "radio_circulo" a un int o float, gracias de ante mano por la ayuda.

```
radio_circulo=input ("escriba el radio del circulo: ")
area_circulo= pi * radio_circulo ** 2
print(area_circulo)
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: El código, los errores y los datos de prueba se comparten como texto; nosotros tampoco te vamos a responder con imágenes.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. las imágenes son útiles para mostrar un resultado o idea deseada, pero evita usarlas para mostrar código y coloca un ejemplo replicable para que sea mas facíl encontrar una respuesta, revisa [ask].

Comment: No agregues tu código como imagen, dale formato con el botón que indica `{}`. Además... ¿Qué funciones intentaste utilizar? Tal vez en tu pregunta esté la respuesta ;)

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar las funciones int() o float () de la siguiente manera

```
radio_circulo = int(input("Escribe el radio del circulo: "))
area_circulo = pi * (radio_circulo * radio_circulo)
print(area_circulo)

radio_circulo = float(input("Escribe el radio del circulo: "))
area_circulo = pi * (radio_circulo * radio_circulo)
print(area_circulo)
```

El único cuidado que Tenes que tener con la función Int(), es que si ingresas un valor decimal te va a tirar error.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya pude arreglar el problema, te lo agradezco mucho

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto:

```
import math

radio_circulo = input("Escribe el radio del circulo: ")
if radio_circulo.strip().isdecimal():
    radio_circulo = int(radio_circulo)
else:
    radio_circulo = float(radio_circulo)

area_circulo = math.pi * (radio_circulo * radio_circulo)
print(area_circulo)
```

Con esto te ahorras que te salga error si el número es decimal o no.

PD: perdón si tardé algo de tiempo, soy nuevo en la programación y lo hago con la mejor intención posible (aunque lento).